# non commutative elements in the fundamental group of a closed hyperbolic surface

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,hyp)$ be a closed hyperbolic surface. fix a point $m$ in $M$ and denote by $G=\pi_1(M,m) $.
now let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $G$ such that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ does not commute . my first question is why $<\alpha,\beta>$ is of inifinite index in $G$ and my second question:  Let  $n$ be the least positive integer  such that any subgroup generated by $n+1$  non commutative elements of $G$ is necessary of finite index in G what do we know about $n$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the first question: because it is free, and every subgroup of finite index is the fundamental group of a finite cover of the surface (which is again a hyperbolic surface). The answer to the second question is "infinity". Take any free non-abelian subgroup $F$ of the surface group. The group $F$, being free, contains free subgroups $F_n$ of arbitrary rank $n$. The generators of $F_n$ do not commute and do not generate a subgroup of finite index.

Comment: what i know is that every infinite index subgroup is free and your saying that it is an equivalence 

Comment: That is correct. A finitely generated subgroup of a surface group is either of finite index or free.

Comment: how do you know that <alpha,beta> is free ? the only method i know is since <alpha,beta> is of infinite index then it is the fundamental group of a non compact hyperbolic surface and we know that such groups are free 

Comment: @student: a closed surface group isn't 2-generator, so your group must be infinite index (and hence free).

Comment: @ kent i guess you meant a closed hyperbolic surface and thanks for your useful comment

Comment: Besides the question is well-understood, I'd like to  comment that the words ``commutative" in the title and body of the question  must read ``commuting".

Answer (score 2):

These questions are the subject of a very nice paper of W. Jaco:

William Jaco. On certain subgroups of the fundamental group of a closed surface. Proc. Cam- bridge Philos. Soc., 67:17–18, 1970.